# RSS feed with highest rated recent questions for a given tag

Tags: support, tags, feed

How do I get the RSS feed of a given tag with the ten most rated questions **asked during the last week?**

Someone seems to have managed to do this for the Python tag:

http://python-weekly.blogspot.in/2018/04/cxxii-stackoverflow-python-report.html

I will like to get a similar RSS feed for the Pandas tag.

Comment: What Stack Exchange site? Stack Overflow? Or for all Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like an RSS feed, but the result of an API call.
A similar call for pandas looks like this (you'll have to convert 'one week ago' to a Unix timestamp):

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1522540800&order=desc&max=10&sort=votes&tagged=pandas&site=stackoverflow

[image]

The relevant documentation about the call is [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions).