# Can we get RSS feeds for hot questions tagged X?

Tags: feature-request, tags, hot-questions, feed

> Similar to:
>
> - [RSS feed of hot questions during the week for specific tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62364/812128) (11 years ago)
> - [RSS feed with highest rated recent questions for a given tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309921/812128) (3 years ago)

I would like to be able to subscribe to, for example, *hot questions tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) from the last week on Stack Overflow*. 
Eventually, a feed for [Hot answers tagged `c`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/hot?filter=week) would also suffice.